# Simplification of if statement with an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I have an if statement as shown below, where I am checking to see if all values in the `count` array equal zero.

```
if (count[1] == 0 && count[2] == 0 && count[3] == 0 && count[4] == 0 
&& count[5] == 0 && count[6] == 0) {

}
```

Is there a way to simplify this statement? Also, note that I do not want to check `count[0]`.

Comment: You can use a loop (starting at 1 in your case) to set a boolean result variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) and [`allMatch(IntPredicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.IntPredicate-).

```
if (IntStream.of(count).allMatch(x -> x == 0)) {
    // ...
}
```

which will include `count[0]`, to exclude `count[0]` you might instead do

```
if (IntStream.rangeOf(1, count.length).allMatch(x -> count[x] == 0)) {

}
```

or (thanks [@Louis Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman))

```
if (IntStream.of(count).skip(1).allMatch(x -> x == 0)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'd tend to write the shorter `IntStream.of(count).skip(1).allMatch(x -> x == 0)`

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use a simple for loop to iterate over the `count` array and check the values of the elements contained within the array to identify if they have a value of zero or not.

```
public boolean isAllZero(int[] array){
   for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
      if(array[i] != 0){
         return false;
      }
   } 
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8

```
 boolean  isAllZero = Arrays.asList(myArray).stream().allMatch(val -> val == 0);
```